# Converting RAW into JPEG in Photos

Tags: photos

Is there a way, in Apple Photos, to convert a lot of RAW pictures into JPEGs and delete the RAW version, to save space? I'm looking for an automatic way of converting all RAW pictures into JPEG as I have several thousands.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can select the RAW photos, then select "Export..." from the File menu.

[image]

There you can select JPEG as the file format, then also select any options for size and quality you desire.

[image]

Comment: I'm aware how to export them. I need to convert several thousands raw photos. My question is how to do it not one by one.

Comment: As the answer showed, you can export many photos at once.

Answer (score 0):

What I do:

1. Create a smart album named "RAW to archive" which is set with the following:

   - Match all the rules
   - Photo is RAW
   - Date Captured is not in the last 1 years
2. Export all the images from that album into a folder on your hard drive, with the following settings:

   - Photo kind: JPEG
   - JPEG Quality: Maximum (or High, or whatever)
   - Color Profile: Most Compatible
   - Size: Full Size
   - Include: Title, Keywords, and Description
   - Include: Location Information
3. Delete the images from your library
4. Reimport the folder you just exported to

Note that this will flatten any edits you made to the originals. (I figure if I've had a file sitting around for over a year I'm *probably* done with it...) It will also remove the images from any albums they're in.

I have also had trouble with Photos eating up a lot of memory when exporting a huge number of images; it's best to limit this process to only a few months' worth of photos at a time.

Answer (score -3):

Clean you mac 3 will do it, it finds all your raw and converts them, but be careful what you ask it to do and i believe theres a cost